# What is the difference between Circular Dependency and Circular Reference or the difference between Dependency and Reference?

Tags: c#, java, dependencies, preference

As stated in the question, Could any one tell me about the difference between Circular Dependency and Circular Reference or the difference between Dependency and Reference?

I feel quite unclear and can't answer my friend's question when he asked me to distinguish these two definitions.

Thanks

Comment: Is it Circular Reference ? or Circular Preferences ??

Comment: never heard of circular preference. What is the context?

Comment: just a different of using terms, the same

Comment: Sorry guys it's Reference not Preference, have just edited the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circular dependency would arise at build or compile time when dependencies are evaluated.

A [chain of] circular *reference[s]*, assuming that's what you're talking about, arises in a cyclic object graph, at runtime.

Never heard of a 'circular preference'.